# How to properly lock with concurrent multiple requests

Tags: c#, caching, concurrency

I have an auto refresh cache in our system, which is running into some issues due to race conditions.

During start up the `_internalCache` which is a concurrent dictionary is empty.

This was implemented years ago as a generic auto refresh cache used across our system.

The refresh action which is causing a most of the trouble, refreshes a few thousand rows from the database.

```
public bool TryGet(TKey key, out TValue value)
{
    if (_internalCache.TryGetValue(key, out value))
    {
        return true;
    }
    lock (_internalCache.SyncRoot)
    {
        this._refreshCacheAction(this._internalCache);
        return _internalCache.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }
}
```

If multiple requests come in at the same time (which happens more often than I wish would) Then, we refresh our cache multiple times.

**Edit:**
After further discussion from the comments,  it looks like this cache is Seriously broken.  Several of our customers are experiencing timeouts, which I need a quick hotfix.

How can I prevent multiple refreshes to the cache?
(Jenky hacks are welcome)

Comment: What about a `ConcurrentDictionary` or a [`MemoryCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-5.0)?

Comment: _internalCache  is the equivalent of a ConcurrentDictionary

Comment: @gunr2171 I'm using a concurrent dictionary, but how would that help? I'll add some details for clarification but the issue is on start up when the dictioanry is empty

Comment: This seems like the fundamental issue with concurrent requests - at some point you need to either put your foot down and say "no, each request will be handled one at a time", or accept "eventual consistency", where each time you hit the cache the results might be slightly different.

Comment: @gunr2171 what about during start up when the dictionary is empty, but there is a queue of request still in IIS about to hit?

Comment: What is the intention of the `lock (_internalCache.SyncRoot)`? Is it to prevent multiple threads from refreshing the cache?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I came across this code  in the Repository, it appears that was their original though but it looks like it just make it wait longer since all the refreshes become sync LOL

Comment: It's unclear what `_refreshCacheAction` does, but are you perhaps looking for [ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.getoradd?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: @johnny5 What do you do in _refreshCacheAction? Looks like it's independent of the not found key? Do you refresh/rebuild the whole cache on every miss?

Comment: @Xerillio The refresh action is a generic thing to do when it can't find a key in the dictionary.  However in this case its a long running operation which ends up 
pulling a few 1000 rows from the db to update a chunk of the cache

Comment: Yeap, judging from this little snippet, the whole design of the cache seems seriously broken. You may have to redesign it from scratch (almost).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the design looks flawed. Maybe even a standard component like ConcurrentDictionary or MemoryCache can be used.

However, one possible hotfix is to check again for the value in the internal cache inside the lock. This should reduce the number of times the refresh action is executed.

```
public bool TryGet(TKey key, out TValue value)
{
    if (_internalCache.TryGetValue(key, out value))
    {
        return true;
    }
    lock (_internalCache.SyncRoot)
    {
        // cache has already been refreshed
        if (_internalCache.TryGetValue(key, out value))
        {
           return true;
        }

        // refresh cache
        this._refreshCacheAction(this._internalCache);
        return _internalCache.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be certain that the class containing `TryGet` is a singleton instance across all calls, in that it should only be created once during the application lifetime. A private instance constructor combined with a static property on the class that references the single instance, constructed in the static constructor of the class, is sufficient:

```
public class ASingletonClass
{
    static ASingletonClass()
    {
         Instance = new ASingletonClass();
    }

    private ASingletonClass()
    {
    }

    public static ASingletonClass Instance { get; private set; }
}
```

Also, replace the SyncRoot call with a new object field in your class set to `new object()`. Newer collections like ConcurrentDictionary don't support SyncRoot.